# Does Pybind allow Python object to store pointer to C++ std::array?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a C++ struct represented in Python using Pybind. It receives data during callbacks but is only allowed to process the data in a final callback.

I'd like to pass the data (`std::array`s) without copying it, so the final callback can read it:

```
struct CppPythonObject
{
    // Update the pointers here
    void receiveData1(const Data* data1){}
    void receiveData2(const Data* data2){}
    
    void useAllData()
    {
        // Access the pointers
    }

    Data* _data1{nullptr};
    Data* _data2{nullptr};
};
```

I see Pybind allows passing C++ arrays by reference, converting to numpy:

https://alexsm.com/pybind11-buffer-protocol-opencv-to-numpy/

But does Pybind support a Python object caching pointers to `std::array`?

Comment: You should be able to get a pointer to the underlying buffer using the `std::array::data()` method and do something very similar to that OpenCV example.

Comment: @MilesBudnek the only problem with that example is they don't store a pointer to the data within Python, they just read and use it immediately.